# ordering = ['-date_posted'] does not work

Tags: python, django

I have this class and I wanted to sort the posts of my blog by date posted but it does not work and gives me this error what should I do?

Thanks in advance

```
FieldError at /
Cannot resolve keyword 'date_posted' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, body, id, title
```

views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime
from posts.models import post
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import ListView



# Create your views here.


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = post 
    template_name = 'website/welcome.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
```

post model

```
class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

Comment: Please include the 'post' model.

Comment: I think you didnt migrate after adding date_posted to your model.

Comment: You may don't have `date_posted` field in your `post` model, try to add `date_posted=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` then makemigrations and migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` in your model. Also I think the field `body` should have a `TextField` instead of CharField (I'm guessing this is the body of the blog).

Lastly, in Python, by convention, your class names should begin with capital letter. So instead of `class post(models.Model)`, you can change it to `class Post(models.Model)`.

**Bringing everything together, Your model should look like this**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`.